# What Is the exact shape of Mosafeha (المصافحه)?

Tags: practical-islam, greetings

I am aware that Mosafeheh (المصافحه) is a kind of greetings which is famous between Muslims as an Islamic deed and apparently has a Thawab (reward). Actually it seems to be shake-hands. But  I'd like to know regarding the circumstances of Musafehe: how precisely shall we do it?

Comment: What is mosafeha?

Comment: @servant-of-Wiser It's [a handshake](http://www.islaam.org/etiquettes/Etiqu-18.htm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

المصافحة is merely the action of shaking hands, and it is not specific to Muslim.

It is mentioned that if a muslim were to greet another muslim, and shake hands, his sins would fall away like the leaves of a tree.

> إِنَّ الْمُؤْمِنَ إِذَا لَقِيَ الْمُؤْمِنَ فَسَلَّمَ عَلَيْهِ وَأَخَذَ
>   بِيَدِهِ فَصَافَحَهُ تَنَاثَرَتْ خَطَايَاهُمَا كَمَا يَتَنَاثَرُ
>   وَرَقُ الشَّجَرِ
>
> when a believer meets another believer and gives greeting and takes
>   his hand and shakes it, their sins/mistakes would fall away like the
>   leaves of a tree fall away.

[الطبراني](http://library.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?bk_no=475&hid=253&pid=280459)